# Keybinding for buffer word count

Tags: key-bindings, functions, keyboard-macros

The following in my `.emacs` file does not produced the desired result of showing me the word count for the current buffer (it "does nothing"):

```
(global-set-key (kbd "<f9>") (kbd "C-u M-="))
```

Is this because `M-=` is an interactive function? Would I need a function to do this?

Comment: Normally you bind keys to functions by name (i.e., `'count-words`), rather than to other keybindings. You can find the name of a function bound to a key with the command `C-h k`. i.e., `C-h k M-=` will tell you the function name is `count-words-region`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

simply

`(global-set-key (kbd "<f9>") 'count-words)`

Answer (score 7):

Your binding does successfully run the keyboard macro you've specified.

The *problem* is that the resulting message does not remain in the echo area long enough for you to see it, which is a side-effect of invoking the command via a keyboard macro (you will see the same problem if you record the macro with <kbd><f3></kbd><kbd>C-u</kbd><kbd>M-=</kbd><kbd><f4></kbd>).

If you open the messages buffer with <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>e</kbd> and then use your binding again, you'll see the message being generated.

> Is this because `M-=` is an interactive function?

Your terminology is mixed up. `M-=` is not a function. `"M-="` is a *keyboard macro* representing the key sequence <kbd>M-=</kbd> which is bound to the *interactive function* `count-words-region`.

(Note also that you *cannot* bind keys to **non**-interactive functions.)

> Would I need a function to do this?

To get the behaviour you're looking for, yes (and djangoliv has provided the appropriate answer for that).